# Upgrading Ruby version And Rails Compatibility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version-control, rvm, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi guys I wonder if someone could explain the problem I'm having so that I can understand whats going on.

I am currently running ruby 2.2.2 and rails 5. I have a small test app and all is working fine. I decided to upgrade ruby to version 2.4.0, for no other reason than I think I should know how to do it and the resulting pitfalls etc, so a learning exercise.

After updating ruby to 2.4.0 which goes fine the command `rails -v` returns rails not installed. If i then revert to the older ruby 2.2.2 `rvm use ruby-2.2.2` run `rails -v` then rails 5.0.1 is returned. Whats happening here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RVM gives you a separate gem directory for each and every Ruby version and gemset. This means that gems must be explicitly installed for each revision and gemset. Usually the migration process is as follows:

```
rvm use ruby-2.4.0 
# or `rvm --default use ruby-2.4.0` if you want to use 2.4.0 from now on
gem install rails -v 5.0.1 # an example, use any version you like
gem install bundler
bundle install # to install all other project gems
```

See the [RVM gemsets documentation page](https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for taking time to answer. I wonder if you could break it down into baby steps for me as I still have some fundamental pieces of the puzzle missing. Its a steep curve. What steps do I need to take then so that I can run rails 5 with my upgraded 2.4.0 installation? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Awesome thanks for taking the time, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Extending @Slava.K 's answer

> I have a small test app and all is working fine. I decided to upgrade
>   ruby to version 2.4.0, for no other reason than I think I should know
>   how to do it and the resulting pitfalls etc, so a learning exercise.

- When you upgrade ruby to 2.4.0, this becomes your new ruby version
  number, thus you won't have any reference to `rails` and `bundler`.
- You would need to do `gem install rails -v x.x.x` and `gem install
  bundler`.
- Now when you do `rails -v`, this will print a version
  number of the installed rails for your given Ruby.

> After updating ruby to 2.4.0 which goes fine the command rails -v
>   returns rails not installed. If i then revert to the older ruby 2.2.2
>   rvm use ruby-2.2.2 run rails -v then rails 5.0.1 is returned. Whats
>   happening here?

- As I have mentioned above already, installing rails is imperative when you upgrade Ruby. So no rails installed, no version number to display

---

- `gem env home` => `../versions/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared`

  - Will show you the location of installed the gems.
- I perefer to use [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#groom-your-apps-ruby-environment-with-rbenv) over `rvm`